# how to open all the links based filename on webpage table in one go and open in new tab

Tags: javascript, python, html, anchor, browser-automation

Have to automate this manual work ? any extension or query or script?
any ideas how to do it

1. Open page in with Filename anyfile.xlsx
2. Right Click on Submit link and `select open in new tab`
3. Replace in URL `&ID=9012389` with `&thevalue=g` and submit
4. Repeat Step 2 for next submit link

[image: Filename]
[image: Links]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Press F12 to open javascript console and paste

```
[...document.querySelectorAll('a')]
    .filter(a => a.href.match(/Submit/))
    .forEach(a => window.open(a.href.replace('&ID=9012389','&thevalue=g'))))
```

Allow pasting if console asks confirmation.

Comment: thanks have to try in debugger console . url to updates are `https://api-myurl.com/Lists/checklist?id=312314&runId=113146123&ID=9012389` . how can i filter all the urls based on `runid=113146123` it is constant and then replace the `&ID=9012389` with `&thevalue=g`

Comment: .filter(a => a.href.match(/runid=113146123/))

Comment: urlpath?id=22423&requestId=1614800638070&lD=1000018 anywhy we can replace &lD=1000019, &lD=1000023, &lD=1000045, &lD=1000215....so on upto 50 ids ? with &thevalue=g ? or any value in `&ID` will this work `ID=@"^\d{10}$"`

Comment: Of course `a.href.replace(/&ID=[0-9]+/,'&thevalue=g')`

Comment: `[...document.querySelectorAll('a')].flat(a => a.href.match(/requestId=*?/))[1].outerHTML` theoutput gives one value
`"<a href="/path/RunUpdate?id=27689&amp;requestId=1614932405112&amp;ln=1000043833" target="_new">Submit</a>" ` @mugiseyebrows how to print all the outerHTML from arraylist

Comment: looks like theres `&amp;` instead of `&` in url

Comment: print where? to console? `[...document.querySelectorAll('a')].filter(a => a.href.match(/requestId=*?/)).forEach(a => console.log(a.outerHTML))`

Comment: I was to capture these links and and then replace with the tags '&thevalue=g' the console did perfect

Comment: can you pls share the replacing part too capturing is working

Comment: `[...document.querySelectorAll('a')].filter(a => a.href.match(/requestId=*?/)).forEach(a => console.log(a.outerHTML.replace(/&ID=[0-9]+/,'&thevalue=g')))`